# Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following datatables:

[image]

When I enter the data to the `participantes_atividades` table it shows me this error:

> Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO participantes_atividades (cd_p,cd_ati) VALUES ('$p','$cd')";

if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($connect)))
```

Comment: Do you have auto increment turned off or something?

Comment: Well it's obvious isn't it? You are trying to inser the record with key that already exists..

Comment: *"Any advices?"* ... Don't try and enter duplicate data in the primary key field(s)?

Comment: The goal of Primary Key is to make sure you only have one occurrence. So why try insert something with the same ID in the first place?

Comment: The primary key is composed by "cd_p" and "cd_ati" together (PFK)

Comment: Also recommended reading: - sql injection - prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a pair of values that are already stored in this table

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fgwnsq
I have this modal when I press "Adicionar" it add's the participant to the mysql table, it get the unique value of the "cd_p" and "cd_ati"

Comment: Ok, i think i wasnt clear enought xD, I Have the "participantes" table that stores people information and "atividades" table that stores the activities information, then people can join the activities for example, I have the soccer and golf activities wich there "cd_ati" is 1 and 2. What i want to do is to insert the same person (example: cd_p = 1) in both activities so it would look like this:
"INSERT INTO participantes_atividades (cd_p,cd_ati) VALUES ('1','1')";
"INSERT INTO participantes_atividades (cd_p,cd_ati) VALUES ('1','2')";

Comment: so whe i execute this query it insert double the values but I dont know why 
if (mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO participantes_atividades (cd_p,cd_ati) VALUES ('1','2')") or die (mysqli_error($connect)))

Comment: To repeat: "You are trying to insert a pair of values that are already stored in this table". To catch this situation, make a SELECT statement first and if it returns any rows, do nothing and output "Activity is already in the database" or something similar,

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting data in "participantes" then the value being inserted in "codigo participante" already exists. A primary key field needs to be unique, which your data insert is violating.
It would be similar to other table.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, i had the click event repeated and it was
duplo registo do evento click sobre o elemento, e consequente dupla chamada do ajax para remover e adicionar o registo